# jQuery css selector match form array names

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

**html**

```
<input name="single">

<input name="multi[]">
<input name="multi[]">

<input name="multi_keys[my]">
<input name="multi_keys[key]">
```

**jQuery**

```
var match_single      = $('[name="single"]');
var match_multi       = $('[name="multi"]'); // No match
var match_multi_keys  = $('[name="multi_keys"]'); // No match

console.log(match_single.length);
console.log(match_multi.length);
console.log(match_multi_keys.length);
```

It will only match `match_single` because the other selectors are not correct.

How can I make them match the form field arrays as well?

**I could do this:**

```
var match_multi       = $('[name="multi[]"]');
```

but how can I match when there are keys inside and they are unknown? I would like to write it like this:

```
$('[name="multi_keys*');
```

Comment: Don't match by attribute values, prefer class selectors.

Comment: @dfsq I'm working with a form where I don't have much control over the html output. I need to figure out some way with jQuery and the dom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `^=` which matches what an attribute starts with:

```
$('[name^="multi"]')
```

Note that this will match **both** `name="multi[]"` and `name="multi_keys[]"`. If you wish to select `multi[]` and `multi_keys[]` separately, you can simply add the opening square bracket to that selector:

```
$('[name^="multi["]')
```

...and:

```
$('[name^="multi_keys["]')
```

---

> `[att^=val]`
>
> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value begins with the prefix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.
>
> – [W3C's Selectors specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)

Comment: That's really brilliant! I'm really glad that you thought of that pitfall and a fix for it as well.

Answer (score 0):

use the `*` before  the `=` like this `$('[name*="multi"]');`

```js
var match_single = $('[name="single"]');
var match_multi = $('[name*="multi"]'); // No match
var match_multi_keys = $('[name*="multi_keys"]'); // No match

console.log(match_single.length);
console.log(match_multi.length);
console.log(match_multi_keys.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="single">

<input name="multi[]">
<input name="multi[]">

<input name="multi_keys[my]">
<input name="multi_keys[key]">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query these inputs by matching the prefix of the input names, like `$('[name^=multi_keys]')` so it will pick up elements which' `name` starts with `multi_keys` . But it is quite hacky.